# Writing a VBScript serializer

Tags: serialization, vbscript

I need a purely text serialization of an object in VBScript.

Does VBScript provide any built-in support for serialization or is it up to me to enumerate the properties and put them in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, VBScript doesn't have any object serialization functionality built in. You will have to implement it yourself (or try finding some ready-made solutions).

Answer (score 2):

Thought this might be useful to someone who got here from Google.

You could use a [JSON serializer](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp). (for ASP) Though I've noticed it has issues with [COM objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5328858/89789). (Solved w/ Hack) As long as you're mostly serializing basic VBScript classes you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another

[http://code.google.com/p/aspjson](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/)

Answer (score 0):

And here is my shameless self promotion:

https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON

> A fast classic ASP JSON parser and encoder for easy JSON manipulation to work with the new JavaScript MV* libraries and frameworks