# JSON.Stringify fails on Scripting.Dictionary objects

Tags: javascript, json, com, asp-classic, vbscript

I am working on an ASP classic project where I have implemented the JScript JSON class found [here](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp). It is able to interop with both VBScript and JScript and is almost exactly the code provided at [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html). I am required to use VBScript for this project by the manager of my team.

It works very well on primitives and classes defined within ASP. But I have need for Dictionary objects which from my knowledge are only available through COM interop. (via `Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`) I have the following class which represents a product: (ProductInfo.class.asp)

```
<%
Class ProductInfo

    Public ID
    Public Category
    Public PriceUS
    Public PriceCA
    Public Name
    Public SKU
    Public Overview
    Public Features
    Public Specs

End Class
%>
```

The `Specs` property is a Dictionary of key:value pairs. Here's how I'm serializing it: (product.asp)

```
<%
dim oProd
set oProd = new ProductInfo
' ... fill in properties
' ... output appropriate headers and stuff
Response.write( JSON.stringify( oProd ) )
%>
```

When I pass an instance of `ProductInfo` to `JSON.Stringify` (as seen above) I get something like the following:

```
{
    "id": "1547",
    "Category": {
        "id": 101,
        "Name": "Category Name",
        "AlternateName": "",
        "URL": "/category_name/",
        "ParentCategoryID": 21
    },
    "PriceUS": 9.99,
    "PriceCA": 11.99,
    "Name": "Product Name",
    "SKU": 3454536,
    "Overview": "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..",
    "Features": "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..",
    "Specs": {}
}
```

As you can see, the `Specs` property is an empty object. I believe that the JSON stringify method knows that the `Specs` property is an object, so it appends the `{}` to the JSON string around the *stringified* output. Which in this case is an empty string. What I expect it to show, however is not an empty object. See below:

```
"Specs": {
    "foo":"bar",
    "baz":1,
    "etc":"..."
}
```

I believe the problem area of the JSON library is here: (json2.asp)

```
// Otherwise, iterate through all of the keys in the object.

for (k in value) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
        v = str(k, value);
        if (v) {
            partial.push(quote(k) + (gap ? ': ' : ':') + v);
        }
    }
}
```

I postulate that the problem with the above code is that it assumes that all objects inherit from the `Object` class. (The one that provides `hasOwnProperty`) However I think that it's likely that COM objects don't inherit from the `Object` class — or at least the *same* `Object` class. Or at least don't implement whatever interface is required to do `for ... in` on them.

**Update:** While I feel it is irrelevant for the question to be answered — I expect some sort of web client to request (via http) the JSON representation of this object or a collection of this object.

**tl;dr The question:** What should I do to make it so that the `Scripting.Dictionary` can be output properly as JSON instead of failing and returning just an empty string? Do I need to 'reinvent the wheel' and write my own `Dictionary` class in VBScript that *does* act as a normal object in ASP?

Comment: That JSON output looks perfectly fine to me. It's not clear what the problem is; how is the JSON (string form) going to be consumed?

Comment: @Pointy I updated the OP. I have added expected use of JSON string and clarified what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript’s `for...in` construct (which is used in the JSON serializer you refer to) only works on native JS objects.  To enumerate a `Scripting.Dictionary`’s keys, you need to use an [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ch9zb09%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, which will enumerate the keys of the Dictionary.

Now the `JSON.stringify` method has a nifty way of allowing custom serialization, by checking for the presence of a `toJSON` method on each property.  Unfortunately, you can’t tack new methods on existing COM objects the way you can on native JS objects, so that’s a no-go.

Then there’s the custom stringifier function that can be passed as second argument to the `stringify` method call.  That function will be called for each object that needs to be stringified, even for each nested object.  I think that could be used here.

One problem is that (AFAIK) JScript is unable to differentiate VBScript types on its own.  To JScript, any COM or VBScript object has `typeof === 'object'`.  The only way I know of getting that information across, is defining a VBS function that will return the type name.

Since the execution order for classic ASP files is as follows:

- `<script>` blocks with non-default script languages (in your case, JScript)
- `<script>` blocks with the default script language (in your case, VBScript)
- `<% ... %>` blocks, using the default script language (in your case, VBScript)

The following could work — but *only* when the `JSON.stringify` call is done within `<% ... %>` brackets, since that’s the only time when both JScript and VBScript `<script>` sections would both have been parsed and executed.

The final function call would be this:

```
<%
    Response.Write JSON.stringify(oProd, vbsStringifier)
%>
```

In order to allow JScript to check the type of a COM object, we'd define a VBSTypeName function:

```
<script language="VBScript" runat="server">
    Function VBSTypeName(Obj)
        VBSTypeName = TypeName(Obj)
    End Function
</script>
```

And here we have the full implementation of the vbsStringifier that is passed along as second parameter to JSON.stringify:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server">

    function vbsStringifier(holder, key, value) {
        if (VBSTypeName(value) === 'Dictionary') {
            var result = '{';
            for(var enr = new Enumerator(value); !enr.atEnd(); enr.moveNext()) {
                key = enr.item();
                result += '"' + key + '": ' + JSON.stringify(value.Item(key));
            }
            result += '}';
            return result;
        } else {
        // return the value to let it be processed in the usual way
            return value;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Of course, switching back and forth between scripting engines isn’t very efficient (i.e. calling a VBS function from JS and vice versa), so you probably want to try to keep that to a minimum.

---

Also note that I haven’t been able to test this, since I no longer have IIS on my machine.  The basic principle should work, I’m not 100% certain of the possibility to pass a JScript function reference from VBScript.  You might have to write a small custom wrapper function for the JSON.stringify call in JScript:

```
<script runat="server" language="JScript">
    function JSONStringify(object) {
        return JSON.stringify(object, vbsStringifier);
    }
</script>
```

after which you can simply adjust the VBScript call:

```
<%
    Response.Write JSONStringify(oProd)
%>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That helps me understand the intricacies of how this all works. I knew the part about JScript not knowing the specific type. But the order in which things are processed is new information to me. Also I didn't think to recurse into another `JSON.stringify` call within my own Dictionary stringifier function. See my answer for how I implemented that. I had to overcome VBScript's inability to pass a function as an argument. Do you know if that would still apply if the argument were a JScript function?

Comment: No problem, it’s an interesting little puzzle, even if classic ASP is a little outdated... As I wrote in my answer, I fear VBScript will not be able to pass a function as an argument.  However, you _can_ write a wrapper function in JScript which will happily pass a reference to a JScript function.  I’ll update my answer.

Comment: I'm waiting for some free time to test your solution. While mine _works_ I want to see if yours does--It is a much better solution. If it does, then I would like your permission to submit your solution as a patch to the JSON2 parser from ASP Xtreme Evolution.

Comment: While I _still_ have not tested your answer, I feel it is the **right** way to fix the problem. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a function to serialize the Dictionary type myself. Unfortunately, you'll have to go in and do a find & replace on any failed dictionary serializations. (`{}`) I haven't the time to figure out an automated way to do this. You're welcome to fork it on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/sholsinger/stringify-dictionary).

```
Function stringifyDictionary( key, value, sp )

  dim str, val

  Select Case TypeName( sp )
    Case "String"
      sp = vbCrLf & sp
    Case "Integer"
      sp = vbCrLf & Space(sp)
    Case Else
      sp = ""
  End Select

  If TypeName( value ) = "Dictionary" Then
    str = """" & key & """:{" & sp
    For Each k in value
      val = value.Item(k)
      If Not Right(str, 1+len(sp)) = "{" & sp And Not Right(str, 1+len(sp)) = "," & sp Then
        str = str & "," & sp
      End If
      str = str & """" & k & """: "
      If TypeName( val ) = "String" Then
        If val = "" Then
          str = str & "null"
        Else
          str = str & """" & escapeJSONString( val ) & """"
        End If
      Else
        str = str & CStr( val )
      End If
    Next
    str = str & sp & "}"
    stringifyDictionary = str
  Else
    stringifyDictionary = value
  End If

End Function

Function escapeJSONString( str )
  escapeJSONString = replace(replace(str, "\", "\\"), """", "\""")
End Function
```

This was written as a function to use with JSON.stringify's `replace` argument (2nd arg). However you cannot pass a VBScript function as an argument. (From my experience) If you were to rewrite this function in JScript you could use it when you're calling JSON.stringify to ensure that Dictionaries do get rendered properly. See the readme on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/sholsinger/stringify-dictionary) for more on that. Here's how I implemented it:

```
dim spaces: spaces = 2
dim prodJSON: prodJSON = JSON.stringify( oProduct, Nothing, spaces)
prodJSON = replace(prodJSON, """Specs"": {}", stringifyDictionary("Specs", oProduct.Specs, spaces * 2))
```

### Known issues:

- The closing `}` for the `Dictionary` serialization will be the same number of indentations as the properties it contains. I didn't have time to figure out how to deal with that without adding another argument which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not inherently encode any type information at all. What JSON enables you to represent is an arbitrary data structure involving either an object or an array of values. Any such object may have an arbitrary number of named properties such that the names are strings and the values are either the constant `null`, the constants `true` or `false`, numbers, strings, objects, or arrays of values.

How such a data structure is realized in any given programming language runtime is your problem :-)  For example, when de-serializing JSON into Java, one might use ArrayList instances for arrays, HashMap instances for objects, and native types for simpler values.  However, it might be that you really want the objects to be some particular type of Java bean class. To do that, the JSON parser involved would have to be somehow guided as to what sort of objects to instantiate. Exactly how that works depends on the JSON parser and its APIs.

(*edit* — when I said "no type information at all", I meant for "object" values; clearly booleans, strings, and numbers have obvious types.)

Comment: I have added what I _expect_ to be output for the `Specs` property of the `ProductInfo` instance to the OP.

Comment: @sholsinger well I'm still not clear as to what domain your serialization is taking place in.  And when there's an object-valued property, a properly-working JSON serializer will most definitely **not** emit "{}" around the string version of the object - it will recursively encode the object exactly as you describe. I suggest that perhaps that "Specs" property does not actually have the value that you think it has.  Either that, or else in the domain where that data structure exists, the "Specs" object cannot be serialized for some reason.

Comment: I have added a bit more context for where and how serialization is occurring to the OP. I agree that the Specs object cannot be serialized for some reason. And I'm wondering why a Scripting.Dictionary in VBScript wouldn't be serializable? The question I guess would be if I should just create my own Dictionary class to replace Scripting.Dictionary and then it would be serializable.

Comment: @sholsinger well I couldn't say why the object can't be serialized as I'm not a VBScript programmer.  It does seem odd but VBScript is a lot older than JSON (well JSON as an interchange format), so maybe the JSON serialization stuff is just not really up to snuff.