# Classic ASP: how to convert a RecordSet to json notation using AXE json implementation

Tags: javascript, json, asp-classic, vbscript, jscript

i'm doing an application with ajax using jQuery and some other tools, and in some part i want to retrieve data with ajax using a classic ASP backend, i saw that exists a good implementation of a JSON class in AXE (Asp extreme edition) framework, and i used it but currently i don't understand how to use it well.

**Edit**: based on the **correct answer** of [JSON.Stringify fails on Scripting.Dictionary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328858/json-stringify-fails-on-scripting-dictionary-objects) Thread, i decided to make a custom function to process Recordsets.

**Edit 2:** Now i'm losing the value data when call *JSON.stringify* inside *function JSONStringify(object)*.

when the Recordset is passed as value to *JSONStringify* everything is ok but when *JSON.stringify* is executed, the "*value*" parameter that must contain the recordset becomes *undefined*

### What i'm expecting (example)

passing a Recordset with from a SQL query `SELECT name, tel FROM users` a see an output like this

```
[
    {"name":"Jonh Smith", "tel":"12345678"},
    {"name":"April Michelson", "tel":"77788802"},
    ...
]
```

passing a Dictionary and see something similar based in the elements declared in dictionary.

```
{
   "element1":"value1",
   "element2":"value2",
   "element3":"value3",
   "element4":"value4",
   "element5":"value5"
}
```

and if i like to support other type object i can do it expanding the function

### Source Code

**getcatalogos.asp**

```
<!--#include file="../includes/conexion.asp" -->
<!--#include file="../includes/json2.asp" -->
<!--#include file="../includes/json-stringify-parser.asp" -->
<%
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
dim aVals(2)

function getCatalogo(tipo, params)
    Dim oConn,oCmd,sSQL,oRs,cont2
    Dim aData,oPar,cont
    dim Info 

    set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    sWhere = ""

    oConn.ConnectionString = strcon
    oConn.Open
    Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn

    select case tipo
        case "g"
            sSQL = " SELECT cve_gr, descr FROM gr ORDER BY descr ;"
        case "z" 
            sSQL = " SELECT cve_zn, descr FROM zn WHERE cve_gr = ? ORDER BY descr ;"
            if IsArray(params) Then
                Set oPar=oCmd.CreateParameter (params(0),129,1,2,params(1))
                oCmd.Parameters.Append(oPar)
            End if
        case else
            getCatalogo = false
            exit function
    end select

    oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
    Set oRs = oCmd.Execute()
    if Not oRs.EOF Then
        response.write(JSONStringify(oRs))
        getCatalogo = true
    else
        getCatalogo = false
    end if
    oConn.Close
end function

aVals(0) = "cve_gr"
aVals(1) = request.querystring("gr")
if Not getCatalogo(request.querystring("t"),aVals) Then
    %>error<%
end if

%>
```

**json-stringify-parser.asp**

```
<!--#include file="vbsTyper.asp" -->
<script runat="server" language="JScript">

    function JSONStringify(object) {
        VBSTypeName(object);
        return JSON.stringify(object,stringifyData);
    }

    function stringifyData(holder, key, value) {
        var sType = '';
        var result;

        //response.write('pre...holder=' + holder + ',key=' + key + ',value=' + value);
        sType = VBSTypeName(value);
        //response.write('post =' + sType);

        //response.write(sType);
        switch(sType){
            case 'Dictionary':
                result = '{';
                for(var enr = new Enumerator(value); !enr.atEnd(); enr.moveNext()){
                    key = enr.item();
                    result += '"' + key + '": ' + JSON.stringify(value.Item(key));
                };
                result += '}';
                return(result);
                break;
            case 'Recordset':
                response.write('here!!!');
                var sTemp = '';
                result = '{';
                while(!value.EOF){
                    if(Len(result) > 0){
                        result += ',';
                    }
                    result += '{';
                    for (var i = value.Fields.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                        if(len(sTemp) > 0){
                            sTemp += ',';
                        }
                        sTemp += '"' + value.Fields(i).name + '":' + JSON.stringify( value.Fields(i).value);
                    };
                    result += '}';
                }   
                result += '}';
                return result;
                break;
            default:
                //response.write(sType);
                return(value);
        }     
        // return the value to let it be processed in the usual way
        return result;
   }

</script>
```

**vbsTyper.asp**

```
<%
Function VBSTypeName(Obj)
    dim sType 
    sType = Cstr(TypeName(Obj))
    response.write(sType)
    VBSTypeName = sType
End Function
%>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the data set you're working with? I'm not sure what you're talking about when you say "I'm losing the value data".

Comment: @natemrice the parameter named value in "function stringifyData(holder, key, value)" is null when the function is executed, but must have a recordset object not a null reference.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to pass objects between languages like this? Has this worked in the past? This might be a better solution: http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/ I have used it in the past and it works well.

Comment: i've never tried before but reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328858/json-stringify-fails-on-scripting-dictionary-objects seems like it's possible, i'll check that library too if i can do what i'm looking for

Comment: That article reveals your problem: Since the execution order for classic ASP files is as follows:

<script> blocks with non-default script languages (in your case, JScript)
<script> blocks with the default script language (in your case, VBScript)
<% ... %> blocks, using the default script language (in your case, VBScript). The following could work — but only when the JSON.stringify call is done within <% ... %> brackets, since that’s the only time when both JScript and VBScript <script> sections would both have been parsed and executed.

Comment: the problem is that using JSON.stringify in <% %> brackets doesn't permits to pass a pointer to a function as reference in the JSON.stringify() function, i assume because this is a behaivor that is outside of definition in VBscript. i'm using VbScript as default language in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kind of achieve it...

**Short version:** i had to modify the json2.asp and hack the stringify() function definition to make it works.

### Long Version

later of see every line of code and giving up on the problem. i decided to take a look into [json2.asp](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp) (AXE Framework) and try to see what it happening there.

look what i see:

[image: screenshot of json2.asp source code]

from the lines 682 to 687 theres a validation if a custom stringy parser is found but later doesn't do anything ... only returns the Object value.

there's speculation from here, because i don't understand well how works every Javascript implementation, but *implying* that the original code runs well, that a standart javascript interpreter (**read everything else but microsoft here**)  will force a serialization of the object in this sutuation, but the JScript interpreter try to parse the object and pass the value as **null**. resulting in that every function that uses a custom stringyfier can't read the object passed in the function.

what i did to resolve ok i inserted this chunk of code before line 688, forcing to execute the custom stringyfier with value directly passed as argument avoiding the implicit parsing.

```
        // Hack & patch to deliver the stringify-ing of the object correctly
        // IDK if this is CORRECT or dont but it works in VbScript
        if(replacer){
            var textval = rep(this,'',value);
            value = textval;
        }
```

later i had to do some changes in **json-stringify-parser.asp** because i had to fix some bugs resulting in this code

```
<!--#include file="vbsTyper.asp" -->
<script runat="server" language="JScript">

    function JSONStringify(object) {
        //VBSTypeName(object);
        return JSON.stringify(object,stringifyData,4);
    }

    function stringifyData(holder, key, value) {
        var sType = '';
        var result;

        //response.write('pre...holder=' + holder + ',key=' + key + ',value=' + value);
        sType = VBSTypeName(value);
        //response.write('post =' + sType);

        //response.write(sType);
        switch(sType){
            case 'Dictionary':
                result = '{';
                for(var enr = new Enumerator(value); !enr.atEnd(); enr.moveNext()){
                    key = enr.item();
                    result += '"' + key + '": ' + JSON.stringify(value.Item(key));
                };
                result += '}';
                return(result);
                break;
            case 'Recordset':
                //response.write('here!!!');
                var sTemp;
                result = '';
                while(!value.EOF){
                    if(result.length > 0){
                        result += ',';
                    }
                    result += '{';
                    sTemp=''
                    for (var i = 0; i < value.fields.Count; i++){
                        if(sTemp.length > 0){
                            sTemp += ',';
                        }
                        //response.write("i=" + i + ",");
                        sTemp += '"' + value.fields.item(i).name + '":' + JSON.stringify( value.fields.item(i).value);
                    };
                    result += sTemp + '}';
                    value.moveNext();
                }   
                result = '{' + result  + '}';
                return result;
                break;
            default:
                //response.write(sType);
                return(value);
        }     
        // return the value to let it be processed in the usual way
        return result;
   }

</script>
```

the part to parse a Recordset works, the part to parse a dictionary is same like the shown in [JSON.Stringify fails on Scripting.Dictionary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328858/json-stringify-fails-on-scripting-dictionary-objects) (a.k.a. i haven't tested yet) but for now i'm done with this.

testing my changes with a recordset object results in this output

```
"{
    {\"clave\":\"BC\",\"descripcion\":\"Cal\"},
    {\"clave\":\"CT\",\"descripcion\":\"Center\"},
    {\"clave\":\"NE\",\"descripcion\":\"Norw\"},
    {\"clave\":\"NO\",\"descripcion\":\"Nore\"},
    {\"clave\":\"NT\",\"descripcion\":\"North\"},
    {\"clave\":\"OC\",\"descripcion\":\"East\"},
    {\"clave\":\"OR\",\"descripcion\":\"West\"},
    {\"clave\":\"PE\",\"descripcion\":\"Pen\"},
    {\"clave\":\"SE\",\"descripcion\":\"Southe\"},
    {\"clave\":\"ZM\",\"descripcion\":\"Met\"}
}"
```

### Questions Left

question that i have left withis kind of hack.

- it's Ok that the output has (") character at the beggining and the
  end and i everything else has escape sencuences ?? or it's something
  that should not occurs.
- this kind of hack is really wrong ... i can do it better, in this
  kind of situation ?
- it's something wrong in my conclusion or arguments ??

Comment: I was also looking at the AXE implementations and this was very helpful so thanks for posting it.  Now I just need to figure out what editor you're using in your screenshot to get that view on the right!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(oRs))
```

Should read something like this:

```
Do Until oRS.EOF
  response.write(JSON.stringify(oRs("cve_gr") & ":" & oRs("descr"))
  oRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: using your suggestion throws me this error *"Error en tiempo de ejecución de Microsoft JScript error '800a139e'

JSON.stringify

/derechovia/includes/json2.asp, línea 685"*

Comment: shown no error but only returns 1 row, i want to convert all values in Recordset into a JSON array

Comment: You have to loop through the recordset. I'll add some more.

Comment: while you answer is technically correct, i want to make a more generic function to deal with recordsets, and this exactly isn't the answer that i'm looking for ... but thanks anyways