# Node.js parsing recordset output

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

I am beginner and learning Node.js and never came across parsing json array. I have following this script.

Finally I log the value of result variable:

```js
var json = '{
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "@responseMessage": "OK"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "responseMessage": "OK"
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        1
    ]
}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
console.log(obj.responseMessage);
```

```
app.post('/loginUser', function (req, res) {
var pum = req.body.pum; //user mail or user phone 
var pw = req.body.pw; //user password
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var request = new sql.Request();
    let query = "DECLARE @responseMessage nvarchar(2) EXEC [dbo].[LoginUser] @pum = N'" + pum + "', @pPwd = N'" + pw + "', @responseMessage = @responseMessage OUTPUT SELECT @responseMessage as N'@responseMessage'"; //SP in a SQL Server
    request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
        }
        sql.close();
        res.json(recordset);
        console.log("IP :" + req.ip + "\n");
        console.log(recordset);
    });
});
```

});

I need parse Stored Procedure Declared @responseMessage output. My Stored Procedure SQL Server Code here:

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoginUser]
    @pum NVARCHAR(254), --user mail or userphone
    @pPwd NVARCHAR(50),
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @userID INT
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE (userphone=@pum or usermail=@pum))
    BEGIN
        SET @userID=(SELECT UserID FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE (userphone=@pum or usermail=@pum) AND PasswordHash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPwd+CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))))
       IF(@userID IS NULL)
            SET @responseMessage='IP' --'Incorrect password'
       ELSE 
           SET @responseMessage='OK' --'User successfully logged in'
    END
    ELSE
       SET @responseMessage='IL' --'Invalid login'
END
```

Node.js output:

```
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { '@responseMessage': 'OK' } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ] }
```

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

OPTION 1:

```
var myRS = recordset;
console.log(myRS.recordsets[0][0]["@responseMessage"]);
```

OPTION 2:
Using Regex example: https://rubular.com/r/jXv0bcaIkPzVOD

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332909/classic-asp-how-to-convert-a-recordset-to-json-notation-using-axe-json-implemen

Comment: I use Regex code :/ https://rubular.com/r/jXv0bcaIkPzVOD